# HP G62 laptop shutdown issues

Tags: shutdown, overheating, hp-laptop

I have an older HP G62-a30SI laptop - i3cpu, 4gb low voltage Ram (but I have normal ram available as well) 500gb hdd, intel hd gpu, broadcom wifi realtek, up-to-date windows 10.

I do not use it with the battery because the battery is defective so it is on AC all the time.

The problem I experience randomly during the day is this:

1. the fan would start spinning loudly which would indicate overheating of the cpu. The bottom of the case would become hot to touch, even the left side of the keyboard.
2. Then the machine would shut itself down. Not just die but proper shut down.
3. When I start it back up again it returns to the previous state, as with hibernation. But all these I have disable in my fault finding quest.

I have done these things already:

- Cleaned out, no dust and new cooling paste,
- Replaced mainboard & cpu
- Upgraded from Win7 to Win10 (64bit)
- Event logs only shows: 
  The system was hibernated due to a critical thermal event.
  Hibernate Time = ‎2016‎-‎10‎-‎31T11:07:46.832281700Z
  ACPI Thermal Zone = _TZ.TSZ0
  _HOT = 360K

The machine is not hot or too warm to touch...

I don't even attempt to run any intensive apps like adobe premier or after effects as it shuts down literally two minutes after starting.

Can someone please give me some advice on what could be the issue and what I should do to narrow it down more? The Windows logs only mention an unexpected shutdown but no more details.

Comment: I have removed the wireless adapter. The laptop gave an error on power up but boots ok. But on first login attempt it shutdown again. Upon restart it took a good 3 mins before showing the login screen. I will try a USB wifi adapter and see if it does it again...

Comment: Nope. Does the same. I only had Firefox open browsing for diagnostic software. Then the fan started up again and it shutdown.

Comment: People are more likely to read your question/answer if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs and bullet points ...

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about your HP laptop model for example G62-143cl? You have only specified the series of the laptop on the model.